# How to search two columns fields in same time in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Apiato Framework for developing API's ,i am doing some searching operations ,i have one column name in my front end page called `cardDetails` it contains `first4 and last4` digits of a card ,but in my database it contains two columns  called `first4` and `last4` .

Now my doubt is if the user searches with both the combined values means it should fetch the values from the both of columns ,can you please help me to achieve this thing..?

`DetailsRepository.php`

```
public $fieldSearchable=[
      'credentials.first4',   //credentials is a relationship which is used in Model
      'credentials.last4      //first4 and last4 are the columns in details table 
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Search Join
as example below,

```
api.domain.test/v1/endpoint?search=age:17;email:john@gmail.com
```

By Default it is an OR operation which equivalent to this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE age = 17 OR email = 'john@gmail.com';
```

Ref: http://apiato.io/docs/core-features/query-parameters/#search-join

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but one of the two methods will work.
Method 1:

```
->where('first4', $request->search_word)->orWhere('last4', $request->search_word)
```

Method 2:

```
->when($request->search_word, function ($query) use($request) {
      $query->where('first4', $request->search_word);
  })
->when($request->search_word, function ($query) use($request) {
      $query->where('last4', $request->search_word);
  })
```

Comment: By default apiato handles searching operation if we add any fields in the `fieldSearchable` array, i am looking for if the  user types both the values(in frontend one column is there cardDetails it contains both first4 and last4 digits in that section)at a time it should display the results.
https://apiato.io/docs/core-features/query-parameters/#searching